# How to recover binary file opened and saved in VSCode?

Tags: visual-studio-code, encoding, binary

I'm working with a new student who's getting started with Python programming in Visual Studio Code. She's exploring and getting to know programming by feel and using VS Code and [kitao/pyxel](https://github.com/kitao/pyxel) to learn the ropes. In that project, one creates `.pyres` files (that are binary/zip files). When that file appeared in the editor, the user clicked on the file, acknowledged the "view this file as text even though it's binary" warning, and then saved it, thereby corrupting the file. And since VS Code and Windows are uncompromising on these sorts of mistakes, all of the work in generating the assets appears to be lost.

Is there any way given a binary file that was opened and re-saved unchanged in VS Code to reverse the changes that VS Code makes to that file? Any insight into what changes VS Code makes to a binary file when opened as text and saved?

Comment: that is why we have backups

Comment: Indeed. Too bad Windows [doesn't keep history without an external drive](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/file-history-in-windows-5de0e203-ebae-05ab-db85-d5aa0a199255) and VSCode doesn't save any history. Gives every new user this special opportunity to learn the same lesson.

Comment: where are the source files that were put in the zip file

Comment: There are no source files. The pyxel project has an editor in which one authors graphics and music and pyxel saves those assets into a file that uses zip encoding.